# Using a defined call back in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, flickr

I have the following code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <title>HTML</title>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#b1").click(function(event) {

                    var pm_url = 'http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.test.echo&format=json&jsoncallback=wooYay&api_key=52c5c9441e7965eb55b7e54246bc6abf';

                    $.ajax({
                        url : pm_url,
                        dataType : 'jsonp',
                        jsonpCallback : 'wooYay',
                        jsonp : 'callback',
                    });

                function wooYay(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    console.log('hi');
                };  

                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <button id="b1">
                Click Me!
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="results"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I view this in Google Chrome dev tools, I clearly see a response like below:

```
wooYay({"method":{"_content":"flickr.test.echo"}, "format":{"_content":"json"}, "jsoncallback":{"_content":"wooYay"}, "api_key":{"_content":"52c5c9441e7965eb55b7e54246bc6abf"}, "callback":{"_content":"wooYay"}, "_":{"_content":"1357519661919"}, "stat":"ok"})
```

But somehow the function wooYay never executes. Also I want to keep the function wooYay in the code block. Could someone please tell me where the error is?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue is you are confusing `jsonCallback` with the AJAX success callback.

The `wooYay` in the `jsonCallback` is to define the wrapper for the response which you see in response data you posted.

jQuery also unwraps the data contained within this wrapper using the name provided or the one it creates if you don't provide one

However this will not run the function you named `wooYay`. This needs to be run in the success callback of $.ajax.

Although it is unorthodox to define your function `wooYay` inside the clcik handler it does work as follows:

```
$("#b1").click(function (event) {

  var pm_url = 'http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.test.echo&format=json&jsoncallback=wooYay&api_key=52c5c9441e7965eb55b7e54246bc6abf';

  $.ajax({
    url: pm_url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'wooYay',
    jsonp: 'callback',
     /* added success callback*/
    success: wooYay
  });

  function wooYay(data) {
    alert('See data in console');
    console.log(data);
  };

});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kT6dq/

> Refactored version to minimize **wooYay** confusion

```
function responseHandler(data) {
   alert('See data in console');
   console.log(data);
 };   


 $("#b1").click(function (event) {
   var pm_url = 'http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.test.echo&format=json&jsoncallback=wooYay&api_key=52c5c9441e7965eb55b7e54246bc6abf';

   $.ajax({
     url: pm_url,
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     jsonpCallback: 'wooYay',
     jsonp: 'callback',
     success: responseHandler
   });
 });
```

Demo(refactored code)   http://jsfiddle.net/kT6dq/1/

Comment: Thanks, Charlietfl! With the refactoring it helps greatly to understand what is what. And I do see where I was missing the success handler. Also I read that $.ajax() is a Low-Level Interface and others like jQuery.getJSON() are just shorthand versions of $.ajax(). So to me if you can master the usage of $.ajax() this may prove beneficial in the long run.

Comment: yes...definitely helps to have full understanding of `$.ajax`. 90-95% of time can use one of the shortcuts `$.post,$.get, $.getJSON` and `load()` is very useful too

Comment: also...if you left out the `jsoncallback` and `jsonp` options, and removed same from url... should work. Most of time can use `callback=?` and jQuery will create a `jsonpcallback` name with timestamp in it to make it unique for cache protection. Remote server wraps JSON in `GET['callback']`

Comment: Charlietfl thanks for the additional info as well. I can tell you that my intent was to play around with $.ajax() and see how much that function alone could do in so far as returning data from an api call. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ has alot to it.

Answer (score 1):

`wooYay` isn't exposed globally, as it is defined in an anonymous function. You could assign it as such...

```
window.wooYay = function(data) { };
```

Answer (score 1):

That's fundamentally impossible.
`wooYay()` is not visible in the global scope.

You should use `getJSON()` normally.

Comment: fundamentally impossible... but it works, likely due to not being called synchrnous  http://jsfiddle.net/kT6dq/

Comment: @charlietfl That's because you're passing a reference to the function, which is in scope. Remove the `success` callback, and you have an error that `window.wooYay` can't be invoked.

Comment: @alex help me understand why need window..wooYay... OP was trying to accomplish same but was missing success callback to reference the function. No error gets thrown from the code he had because `jsoncallback` isn't calling function in window scope